# Retrieving a RavenDB document by a property other than key without querying

Tags: ravendb

Is it possible to load (as opposed to query for) a document from the data store using a property that would return a single document but that isn't the key?

In my scenario, I have Users and Brands. A Brand is a User but a User doesn't have to be a Brand. Each Brand has a UserId property as well as its Id. Is there a way to load a Brand document by its UserId or should I simply create a static index for this and query? I'm wondering whether there's something, perhaps under `IDocumentSession.Advanced` that I could use for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only load a document by its key.  Sorry.

You can construct [meaningful document keys](http://mattwarren.org/2012/07/12/fun-with-ravendb-documents-keys/), which sometimes helps.  I'm not sure it would in the case you described.

It would probably be best to have a static index of Brands by UserId.

Aside - I think the relationship would be better described by "brand *has* a user" instead of "brand *is* a user" - yes?

Comment: Not quite in this case Matt - a User can be a Brand or a Consumer. Maybe `BrandRepresentative` would be more meaningful. I thought I might end up going with an index but wanted to check if there was another option first - thanks!

Comment: That makes more sense, yes.  But if that's the case, you have a one-to-one relationship.  Why not line up the ids?  In other words, consumers/123 would match users/123.  Then you don't need an index.  Another alternative would be to set User as an abstract base class and treat them as [polymorphic entities](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/polymorphism)

Comment: I never even considered that - you're a genius. Cheers Matt!

Comment: Except that it doesn't work. If I give the User and the Brand the same id, the user doesn't even get saved to the data store, because it has the same id as the Brand. I'm using guids for ids rather than letting Raven auto-generate integers, which may have something to do with that

Comment: ah, yes.  You will need to adjust the key manually then.  The key is actually a string of entityname/guid.  This makes things painful sometimes.  string ids are much easier in raven.